# Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree

Tags: openxml-sdk

When I try to add border values to the table in a word document using open xml I get this error.

> (Cannot insert the `OpenXmlElement` "newChild" because it is part of a
>   tree.)

Here is my code :

```
if (sValue == "")
{
   InsideVerticalBorder insideVBorder = new InsideVerticalBorder();
   insideVBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None);
   tblBorders.AppendChild(insideVBorder);
}

else
{
   InsideVerticalBorder insideVBorder = new InsideVerticalBorder();
   insideVBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single);
   tblBorders.AppendChild(insideVBorder);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using CloneNode(true) like this.

```
if (sValue == "")
{
   InsideVerticalBorder insideVBorder = new InsideVerticalBorder();
   insideVBorder.Val = BorderValues.None;
   tblBorders.AppendChild(insideVBorder.CloneNode(true));
}

else
{
   InsideVerticalBorder insideVBorder = new InsideVerticalBorder();
   insideVBorder.Val =BorderValues.Single;
   tblBorders.AppendChild(insideVBorder.CloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: CloneNode(true) worked for my problem of copying a table:

Body bod = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            Table t = bod.Descendants<Table>().Where(tbl => tbl.InnerText.Contains("Table name")).FirstOrDefault();
            t.AppendChild(t.CloneNode(true));

Comment: Using object1.AppendChild(**object2**) resulted  in the error listed for this post.  Changing **object2** to **object2.CloneNode(true)** solved my problem!